# Task description field not available for page layout

Tags: page-layout, tasks, detail-page, standard-field

I have created a Task record type and a page layout for it. A process builder is invoked that then creates a task record. Question is, somehow the task Standard field 'Description' is not available in page layout pallette to place in my page layout. However, in my process, I am able to set value of description.
Adding to this, somehow Description field is not available in setup. I have to see it in workbench!
Yes, I am a system administrator and I have checked permissions (R,E). Am I missing something? Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Description' field in task is labelled as 'Comments' and its available to be added in the page layouts.
For more details check the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=task_fields.htm&type=5)

Comment: There we have it. Thanks alot